# Managed meta data service application, error: some terms will become homograph siblings after this default language change

Tags: managed-metadata

I am using sp 2013. I opened the managed metadata service application. I changed the default language from English to another language.I click on Save. I got this error:

> some terms will become homograph siblings after this default language
>   change. checks logs to find out what they are and fix them before
>   trying to switch the default language.

What is the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A homograph is a word that is spelt the same, but has a different meaning.  You should be able to have a hierarchy that has "Paris" existing in both France and Texas.  To keep things a bit more sane for the user, we don't allow homographs to have the same parent.

So please check and make sure no such term exist.